Using insert_after with ciscoconfparse2
How do I use insert_after()?
In the documentation I checked how to use this method, but having troubles, essentially I want to find a line in the config as an anchor point that I know exists:
!
cable profile downstream DS1
!

And then add more lines after it
cable profile load-balance ALPN
 method utilization us-method modems
 threshold load 30
 threshold stability 70
 policy pure-ds-load
 docsis-policy 1
 interval 300
!
cable profile load-balance ALPY
 restricted
 interval 5
 tag TAG_STB
!

What should I do to accomplish this?

Use ciscoconfparse2 for this task (FYI I am the author).
If you have a list of lines to add in order, reverse() the list... see what I do with all_changes_list below
from ciscoconfparse2 import CiscoConfParse

config = """!
!
!
cable profile downstream DS1
!
!"""

afterSection = """!
cable profile load-balance ALPN
 method utilization us-method modems
 threshold load 30
 threshold stability 70
 policy pure-ds-load
 docsis-policy 1
 interval 300
!
cable profile load-balance ALPY
 restricted
 interval 5
 tag TAG_STB
!
"""

parse = CiscoConfParse(config)

all_changes_list = afterSection.splitlines()
all_changes_list.reverse()

for anchor_obj in parse.find_objects("^cable\s+profile\s+downstream"):
    # Iterate over your *reversed config* and insert lines after the anchor
    for line in all_changes_list:
        anchor_obj.insert_after(line)
parse.commit()  # commit() is req'd any time you finish modifying the config...

